# What are best practices for multi-language database design?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

What is the best way to create multi-language database? To create localized table for every table is making design and querying complex, in other case to add column for each language is simple but not dynamic, please help me to understand what is the best choose for enterprise applications

Comment: See as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227985/whats-the-best-database-structure-to-keep-multilingual-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077305/how-to-use-multilanguage-database-schema-with-orm/4745863#4745863

Comment: I've found this very helpful to me: [Multilanguage Database Design in MySQL](http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=multilanguage-database-design-in-mysql)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

What we do, is to create two tables for each multilingual object.

E.g. the first table contains only language-neutral data (primary key, etc.) and the second table contains one record per language, containing the localized data plus the ISO code of the language.

In some cases we add a DefaultLanguage field, so that we can fall-back to that language if no localized data is available for a specified language.

Example:

```
Table "Product":
----------------
ID                 : int
<any other language-neutral fields>


Table "ProductTranslations"
---------------------------
ID                 : int      (foreign key referencing the Product)
Language           : varchar  (e.g. "en-US", "de-CH")
IsDefault          : bit
ProductDescription : nvarchar
<any other localized data>
```

With this approach, you can handle as many languages as needed (without having to add additional fields for each new language).

---

*Update (2014-12-14): please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27474681/19635), for some additional information about the implementation used to load multilingual data into an application.*

Comment: Yes, no need for multiple columns: key by language. Although here is would be useful to have ProductDescription as nvarchar, I suspect.

Comment: Please add more details in creating business objects in this case, creating separate businees object will be suitable for CMS, but creating one localized business object for other cases

Comment: what if the only language-neutral field is the id? and how exactly do you insert the foreign key reference when inserting a row?

Comment: It's funny, that I was designing a database scheme for a multilingual CMS and had this question in my head aswell. I chose this approach, before I even saw this answer! Thanks for this answer!

Comment: why two table would be require one is product & another one is producttranslation....is there any chance that a product may have multiple detail. thanks

Comment: One thing to note here is that there would either be no PK on this table or ID and Language need to be the composite PK.  Either that, or you need to add a ProductTranslationId field, probably as an identity.

Comment: Sorry if I revive this thread, but I'm facing a similar problem and as it happens I already followed this approach, two tables, one for the contents, other for the translation, and the default language flag, but I have a strong doubt on how to query the database to tell "load the user's language, if that translation does not exist, fall back to the one with the default flag" with just one query. I currently load all the translations and iterate over them in my controller, but that's not the best solution, if there is a lot of data and translations to iterate over...

Comment: @Luca: you should post that as a new question. You can refer to this one, if you like.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I did it already, and it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765175/multi-language-database-with-default-fallback :)

Comment: @Luca: I answered your question, showing what implementation(s) I use to load the data.

Comment: It seems to me that a model that links the foreign-key should be in the object with the fields to be translated and it should point to a single "translations" table shared by all internationalized entities. (e.g. the way the problem is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693508/database-modeling-for-international-and-multilingual-pruposes)

Comment: you can also use encoding for field. In this way you dont need to create separate table

Comment: If you need to perform full-text search on the content then the languages need to be in separate columns. Of course, you can also put them in indexed views with a full-text index.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen I know it has been almost 8 years but, what did you do in that case you mentioned, "what if the only language-neutral field is the id".

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Well, funnily enough you create a table with a single column called `id` :D . To explain, each `id` represents a meaning to which you can attach words from any language in a relational table, so you get two tables, `meaning` (id) and `word` (id, meaning_id), the `id` in the `word` table represents the word id, the `id` in the `meaning` represents the meaning that is universal.

Comment: If in your system there is an admin user who can determine the language of the system, in addition of this answer you can keep all the fields in the first table and fill them on the language change event from the appropriate record of the second table based on selected language then simply use these fields in all of your queries.

Comment: This sounds like [Approach #4](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system/).

Comment: @TimoHuovinen There is a different solution: Simply put "created" and "updated" columns besides the "id".. you never know when you'll need them ;)

Comment: @M4N I think `IsDefault` language flag should be added in the language table not in the `ProductTranslations` table because for all products default language would be same.

Comment: @MD.IBRAHIMKHALILTANIM: In my case, each product could have a different default language, e.g. depending on where it came from, who created it, etc...

Comment: Ok. Now I get it.

Comment: is it bad practice if i saved the name as JSON FIELD in the database?

Comment: This concept and joining will make thing more complicated

Comment: does this mean with each new "translation", I need to create a new table with the same exact fields? (e.g. `EnglishTable[fields: "title", "description"] - FranchTable[fields: "title", "description"]`)

Answer (score 26):

I recommend the answer posted by Martin.

But you seem to be concerned about your queries getting too complex:

> To create localized table for every table is making design and querying complex...

So you might be thinking, that instead of writing simple queries like this:

```
SELECT price, name, description FROM Products WHERE price < 100
```

...you would need to start writing queries like that:

```
SELECT
  p.price, pt.name, pt.description
FROM
  Products p JOIN ProductTranslations pt
  ON (p.id = pt.id AND pt.lang = "en")
WHERE
  price < 100
```

Not a very pretty perspective.

But instead of doing it manually you should develop your own database access class, that pre-parses the SQL that contains your special localization markup and converts it to the actual SQL you will need to send to the database.

Using that system might look something like this:

```
db.setLocale("en");
db.query("SELECT p.price, _(p.name), _(p.description)
          FROM _(Products p) WHERE price < 100");
```

And I'm sure you can do even better that that.

The key is to have your tables and fields named in uniform way.

Comment: the other question is, to create one business object for product? or to create two... in first case it's easy to work with that item, in 2 nd easy to write CMS

Comment: Where is Martin's solution?

Answer (score 14):

I find this type of approach works for me:

```
Product     ProductDetail        Country
=========   ==================   =========
ProductId   ProductDetailId      CountryId
- etc -     ProductId            CountryName
            CountryId            Language
            ProductName          - etc -
            ProductDescription
            - etc -
```

The ProductDetail table holds all the translations (for product name, description etc..) in the languages you want to support. Depending on your app's requirements, you may wish to break the Country table down to use regional languages too.

Comment: I chose this same approach for a project I'm currently working on because my different locales contain very specific information about unit systems and measures to be displayed to users.

Comment: Country and language (locales) are different things. And ISO language codes are natural keys, you eliminate unnecessary join from lang to country.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using next approach:

### Product

ProductID OrderID,...

### ProductInfo

ProductID Title Name LanguageID

### Language

LanguageID Name Culture,....

Answer (score 2):

Martin's solution is very similar to mine, however how would you handle a default descriptions when the desired translation isn't found ?

Would that require an IFNULL() and another SELECT statement for each field ?

The default translation would be stored in the same table, where a flag like "isDefault" indicates wether that description is the default description in case none has been found for the current language.

Comment: @GorrillaApe: see this answer for an example how to fall back to the default language, if the desired language was not found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27474681/19635

Comment: Where is Martin's solution?