# How to design database schema for a content management system (cms) with multiple language support?

Tags: database-design, content-management-system, multiple-languages

I am going to build a site with multiple language support, and I need to have the ability to control the workflow of the articles, companies, products. All with multiple language support and multiple versioning.
Does anyone have the solution for this already or I need to start from scratch?

Comment: It looks like you got some pretty lame answers. Here is a similar question with answers you are probably looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929410/what-is-best-practices-for-multilanguage-database-design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the Database models at [Database Answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) ?

Of course, you could use MS SharePoint.

Have you looked at:

- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

> Joomla is an award-winning content
>   management system (CMS), which enables
>   you to build Web sites and powerful
>   online applications. Many aspects,
>   including its ease-of-use and
>   extensibility, have made Joomla the
>   most popular Web site software
>   available. Best of all, Joomla is an
>   open source solution that is freely
>   available to everyone.

- [Open Source Content Management System List](http://www.la-grange.net/cms)
- [OpenCMS](http://www.opencms.org/en/)

Comment: Hi Mitch,
I am  asking a very specific question, can you give me in more detail? I am lost with hundreds of model :-s

Comment: Thank you Mitch, what I want is the database schema to my solution, or the database design, or any document on the guidance to create a database design of what I want to archieve. Thanks ;)

Comment: This comment gives three very vague answers. All three would, in the present, be mediocre recommendations.

Comment: @gamerzfuse: and your credentials are? Feel free to add a better answer (some 3 years later...)

Answer (score 5):

As your question is very broad, I will attempt to give you an answer with a simple example. This can be extended to every entity you want to store. Let us assume you have an article entity. 
Article (articleID, langID, ENUTitle, ENUContent, authorID)

By default you can store English language content in the main table. The same content or translated content can be stored in a separate language translation table.

Article_Translation(ID, articleID, langID, langTitle, langContent)

example of content

```
insert into article values ('art101','ENU','New Website for Developers','Stackoverflow is new and useful','BKM')

Insert into article_translation (1023, 'art101','FRA','nouveau site Web pour les développeurs','stackoverflow est nouveau et utile','BKM')

Insert into article_translation (1024, 'art101','SPA','nuevo sitio web para desarrolladores','Stackoverflow es nuevo y útil','BKM')
```

Depending on your user language preference, content can either be displayed from article table or article translation table

In general, for every entity that needs translation, you will need a main table and language translation table.