# How to pass viewmodel to controller?

Tags: linq-to-entities, viewmodel

I have a problem with my viewmodel.
I have a `DropDownList` with many translation values (pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227985/whats-the-best-database-structure-to-keep-multilingual-data))

In my controller - HTTPGET:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id) {

            int DropDownListValueId = id;

            SelectListViewModel viewmodel = new SelectListViewModel(0, DropDownListValueId);          

            return View(viewmodel);

        }
```

In my view:

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>      

            <%foreach (var item in Model.DropDownListValue.DropDownListValue_Translation)
              {%>                  
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Name) %><br />           

            <%  } %>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
```

In my controller, HTTPPOST:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SelectListViewModel viewmodel)
{                
    return View();
}
```

My problem: data is not passed in httppost; I think the problem is `foreach` in my view?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, typed viewmodel:

```
<legend>Contacts</legend>
      <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++) { %>

            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts[i],"Contact") %>

        <% } %>
```

With this, I bind my list to the controller!