# How to configure Laravel model attributes in a trait?

Tags: laravel, model, attributes, eloquent, traits

I have a trait called `Multilingual` which uses the model its `lang` and `translation_of` attributes (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299777/1453912) to provide multiple translations of an entity.

Now I want to hide the `translation_of` field from the model when `$model->toArray()` is called, which is - most easily - done through adding it to the `$hidden` attribute. Like this:

```
class Model {
    use Multilingual;

    protected $hidden = ['translation_of'];
}
```

But to keep the original model clean, I want to add the hidden field via the used trait.

I have tried:

1. Adding `protected $hidden = ['translation_of'];` to the trait, which is not allowed: `Undefined: trait declaration of property 'hidden' is incompatible with previous declaration`

   And also not very extensible (It will be overridden by the `$hidden` property of the class, I think..)
2. Adding a boot method to the trait:

   ```
   static function bootMultilingual() {
       static::$hidden[] = 'translation_of';
   }
   ```

   Which (as I suspected) is also not allowed, because of the scope.

Any ideas for a clean way to do this?

Please help!

---

NOTE: To keep it dynamic, I figured it can be done in two ways:

1. Internally: `$this->hidden[] = 'translation_of';`
2. Externally: `$model->setHidden(array_merge($model->getHidden(), ['translation_of']));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override the method where `$this->hidden` is actually used. And that's `getArrayableItems`

```
trait Multilingual {

    protected function getArrayableItems(array $values)
    {
        if(!in_array('translation_of', $this->hidden)){
            $this->hidden[] = 'translation_of';
        }
        return parent::getArrayableItems($values);
    }
}
```