# mysql: simple multilingual content table

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Say I have a simple table, named `content` with the following fields: `id`, `title`, `html`, `modified_date`

I also have a table called `language`, with only the fields `id` and `name`

What would be the best way to make my `content` table multilingual? I thought about using 2 unique identifiers, but i'm not sure how to implement that, and will auto_increments still work when i have multiple unique ids?

(Also I don't like losing my single id-field as a unique identifier, cause i have set up a model in php that allows me to easily create objects based on the table-name and the id.)

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077305/how-to-use-multilanguage-database-schema-with-orm/4745863#4745863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two tables for this. Using "pages" as an example:

**Table:** pages
**Fields:**

- id
- title  (Title in English, used for referencing)
- last_modified

**Table:** page_content
**Fields:**

- page_id  (Foreign key)
- language_id  (Foreign key.  Alternatively, language_code)
- title
- content

Comment: thanks, that looks good. i based my model on your suggestion. i now have a table called `content` (with only language-independent info like `date_created`) and then i have a `contenttranslation` table with `language_id`, `content_id`, `title` and `html`

Answer (score 0):

What about adding to your content table a FK field, language id?

Comment: sure, but i need a way to find the same content in another language. so if i get content 1 with language 2, how would i find the same content in let's language 3?

Comment: @Jules - how do you identify that the two contents are the same, when they are in different languages? If you are saying language and content are M:N then rather than adding a foreign key; add an associative table with columns content id, language id, both of which are FKs to your existing tables.

Comment: by the contents are the same I mean, they are each other's translations. maybe i dindn't make that vary clear