# static and globally filter in sql select statement

Tags: php, sql, global-variables

relating to implementation of [What are best practices for multi-language database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929410/what-is-best-practices-for-multilanguage-database-design/929430#929430)

how can I declare something similar to static variable that describes language in that session

now I use a static and globally variable/Session in PHP and concatenation of it to the query string.

Comment: I think you are looking for sessions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: no, I have the session's language i want to make a proper select in sql, but all of my query just append "and idlng=$lng", I would like to store a state in MySQL for that connection that will define that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports a local, session and global variables. You want to use session.

To set a session variable, simply:

```
SET @key = 'value'
```

All session variables are prefixed with a '@'.

Session variables goes out of scope when the connection is terminated.

In your case, you will still need to `AND` your queries, like:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE lang = @lang
```

You cannot automatically do this.

More info in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html).

Comment: ok, thanks, if I'll make a stored procedure that is a function of @lng ,I'll get the desired affect of setting a global static @lng?

Answer (score 0):

Using an ORM like doctrine would allow you to do things like this using events.
See the method `preDqlSelect()` on this page: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en