# ASP.NET Multi-Lingual Application using Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if anyone would share their experience on what they think as the best strategy to enable dynamic multi-lingual system using .NET

I have a customer who wishes to have an semi-MRP system that stores all Product's Materials and specs. These information will later be used for other modules such as Invoices, Purchasing, Marketing (extracting the information for printing purposes) and many more.

The thing is, he wants everything to be stored multiple languages. He is also unable to fixed the number of languages. Hence, the number of languages will grow throughout time.

So I guess what I am asking is, what is the best strategy to setup a dynamic language enabled website that encompasses the field names (eg, name) and also it's data (eg, Lasker).

Many thanks in advance, Lasker

Answer (score 0):

There are many great articles under this. You can try,

http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-localization

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LocalizationPackage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx

If you still have problems..post the specific question you have.

Comment: The 3 solutions offered only address UI localisation. Have any links or solutions to address the requirements for data that must handle multiple languages?

Comment: @ozzy that has been addressed in this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929410/what-are-best-practices-for-multi-language-database-design