# Solutions to bypass MS-Access system language requirements?

Tags: ms-access

In a 2010 ms-access database, I have a few English-based datasets that I am trying to fit into a form. My operating system was defined with a different language, which causes the program to throw an error about the diffrence, asking me to change my operating system's language settings.

I want the form to work without having to change that. Is there anything in the settings I can change, or anything in the form itself that might possibly avoid this? If you need specific details, ask for them, I'll happily provide them.

Comment: By 'datasets' do you mean tables, or do you mean files external to Access? We developed an Access application for worldwide distribution in our company, and about every three months someone would change their workstation language setting. We just tested for that and had the IT guy change it back. Possibly you could implement a code solution -- depending on specifics.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Tables indeed. How can you change that with code?

Comment: The first link below deals with the concept of supporting multiple languages, and the second gets into specifics and code. In any case, design changes will need to occur. As for any errors you get now, those should be fixed by the design changes, If not, post the error and source.  Good Luck!
What are best practices for multi-language database design? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929410/what-are-best-practices-for-multi-language-database-design

How to implement a multi-lingual database
http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/908560-how-implement-multi-lingual-database

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thank you very much. If i'll implement it before I get any other answer i'll let you know, because in that case I think you deserve the checkmark.