# SQL database design to achieve scalability at early stage

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

The project I am working on has a lot of dependency on foreign languages. In order to capture all required content in foreign languages I have designed the following DB diagram.

[image]

Since I want to address the issue of scalabilty at early stage of DB design, I want to know is this a good way to go? An alternative solution would for each table Products, Agents (and any futher tables) to have its own content/content languages table such as ProductsContent, ProductsContentLanguages, AgentsContent, AgentsContentLanguages.

Splitting and duplicating table structure would shrink table size, and would improve performance, especially since each table would not contain equal number of entries. I believe the difference would be more then obvious  when tables get very large.

So what would be a good database design in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips and links that maybe useful for your current scenario,

["Multilanguage Database Design in MySQL"](http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/index.php?page=multilanguage-database-design-in-mysql)

[What are best practices for multi-language database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929410/what-are-best-practices-for-multi-language-database-design)

[What is the best database design for multi-language data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27014/what-is-the-best-database-design-for-multi-language-data)