# c# mvc multi language support

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a multi-language site with c#. In my database, my columns continue as en_Title, en_Content. I have a function to get the news, I am sending the active language as a parameter to this function.

```
Function
 public static List<Haberler> GetHaber(string lang)
        {
            using (BIRLIKB2BEntities db = new BIRLIKB2BEntities())
            {

                var Haber = db.Database.SqlQuery<Haberler>($"SELECT ID, {lang}_Baslik, {lang}_KisaAciklama, {lang}_Icerik FROM Haberler").ToList();
                return Haber;
            }
        }
```

I want to pull only the language columns according to the language code that comes here. But I guess entity framework is giving error

Error:
**The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'BIRLIKB2BModel.Haberler'. A member of the type, 'Baslik', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.**
`The result of these processes is the output I expected. just reading the columns I send in the function. Is there an alternative way to solve this? can you help?`

```
Table 

ID|tr_Baslik|tr_Aciklama|tr_Icerik|en_Baslik|en_Aciklama|en_Icerik
1 |  Turkey |  Turkey   | Turkey  |English  |English    |English|
```

Comment: Please share your model [Haberler] and your TableInformations of Haberler. Otherwise we only can guess, what the problem is

Comment: I updated it, you can check it again

Comment: if the schema is not fixed i would strongly suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/929430/671619

Comment: @AhmetEnesSöylemez Please add the model class of Haberler on your C# side