# Designing a Localized Database Schema

Tags: database-design, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schema for a multilanguage database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database)

I'm working on a web application that I plan to make available in multiple languages.  As I design the database, I'm going back and forth between two different ways to store localized descriptions and whatnot in the database.

First option is the well-known table_name, table_name_ml type option:

```
TABLE Category (
   ID int,
   ParentID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   Description varchar(255)
)

TABLE Category_ML (
   ID int,
   CategoryID int,
   LocaleID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   Description varchar(255)
)
```

The second option would be to not store the text in the base tables at all, but instead store a token that could be used to lookup the actual localized text elsewhere, like this:

```
TABLE Category (
   ID int,
   ParentID int,
   NameToken varchar(50),
   DescriptionToken varchar(50),
)

// Tables in a separate content management type system
TABLE Content (
   ID int,
   Token varchar(50)
)

TABLE Translation (
   ID int
   ContentID int,
   LocaleID int,
   Value text
)
```

The idea here is that the Content and Translation tables would hold the localized text for many different entities in the database.  The service layer would return the base objects with just the tokens and the view layer would look up the actual text values using the Content/Translation tables - which would be heavily cached.  The Content/Translation tables would also be used for storing other CMS type content (static text on web pages, etc.)

I like the first option because it's tried and true, but the second option seems to have so many other advantages:

1. All my text/localized content is in one place (makes translating easier).
2. Service layer doesn't really need to care about locales.
3. Simplifies queries by not having to join in a bunch of ML type tables.

Since I've never seen a design like this before, I assume I must be missing something.  Any good reasons not to design it this way? Or maybe there's a better option that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Why do you have a Content Table? Couldnt you just use your token to directly look up the translation in the Translation-Table???

Comment: No that I think of it, if the tokens only holds information like <tablename>.<pk>.<fieldname> why would the table category need token-properties anyhow??

Comment: @paskster - The content table is there to avoid duplicating the token column in the translation table.  There would be many translations for a given token.  It also allows you to have RI between the Category table and the Content table if desired.

Comment: @paskster - As for why you would store the token property, you would need to it be able to join between the Category and Content tables in the database.  You could also just store the ContentID on the Category table instead (probably better for efficiency), but storing the token makes it a bit easier to make sense of the raw data when you are looking at the tables.

Comment: You can check this link:
http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/multilanguage-database-design-approach/
although reading the comments is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first say that I have no dealt with localization before so this is really just my opinion and not based on experience.

I like your 2nd option.  As far as the DB goes.. its data and a way to access/manipulate the data.  In this case all the data is there and you will be mostly reading it and have a good way of getting to it.  You can answer the same problem in both scenarios.  I would prefer the 2nd option myself because it reduces crazy tables everywhere.  You are keeping a table around for the specific purpose of translation.  You can reuse it (no creating more tables just for upgrades later) and it maintains integrity.  You could even reuse names if it makes sense somewhere.  Like if you had 'Mantequilla' as a Category and as a Favorite somewhere else.

I like to put related data in one table when possible and not have data related to 'translating' in multiple places.

The only place this may fail is if you have more than just Name and Description for something that needs translation.  Maybe you have Name, Description, Code, Magic Word, Silly Nickname, etc for an item.  Although you could get around this by adding more NameTokens in that relevant table and reusing Name, but this is a bit of a hack.

Just make sure the model meets your needs everyone and it should work fine.  You can always throw in a special translation table if needed later for a specific table.  This wouldn't be to different from creating lots of table although a hybrid solution could be confusing.  It is best to find one way and try to stick to it.

Comment: Having more than just name and description shouldn't be an issue.  The token field is just a free-form piece of text.  For instance, the "NameToken" for a category with ID of 1 might be 'DB.Category.1.Name'.  If I had a field called "MagicWord" on that table, the token for that might be 'DB.Category.1.MagicWord'.  So, generally, the tokens would be named like 'DB.<tablename>.<pk>.<fieldname>'.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: ok well then it seems you have all the cases I can think of planned out :)  Seems like a good model to me.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra option and i think i will bet on this !

- Seperating Database Totally !

REASONS (PROS):

- Pyhsically seperated localized database
- Scaffolding (Generated Presentation Layers)
- Easy Orm

CONS:

- You have to solve UniqueId problem (replication)
- You need to synchronize schema and Non-Localization Data

Comment: Your "pros" are facts, not advantages. The "cons" are quite heavy against the little "pros".

Comment: Serhat didn't mention the killing Pro: for a large db it's optimized against heavy required language info searches - it's already is language separated. But this is good for large dbs only.