# Change report locale for each record?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I have customers from many countries, and for each one I need to generate a page with data on it.

In my report I have a similar query: *SELECT Name, Address, CodLanguage ... FROM Customers*

For each record of this query, I want to generate a page in Jasper Reports with customer data in their respective language *(I know its language through this flag CodLanguage)*.
I want change report language for each customer page *(each record)*. Can i do this using report parameter locale? Or changing some variable for each record? Has anyone had a similar situation? Have any idea what can be done?

**Example**

I need translate the labels: *Name, Address, City, Phone Number and Country* in 10 different languages, according to the customer's country language.
[image]

This example is only a simplification. I will generate between 3 and 6 report pages for each customer, with many other data.

Thanks!

Comment: `I want change report language for each customer page (each record).` - What do you want? Do you want to replace text in fields (data from DB)? Your question is unclear - you should add some image to illustrate your task/problem

Comment: Do you have all this names in different languages in DB?

Comment: You can read about [internationalization](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n), but this help you to show only labels on different languages.

Comment: I need to internationalize the labels. Not in report level, but to each customer record. I don't have these labels names in DB.

Comment: Looks like you question more about DB design. You should edit the question to make it clear. This post maybe help you: [MySQL Database Design with Internationalization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4596385/876298)

Comment: i will see this link: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n

Comment: I see that there is the parameter REPORT LOCALE. My question is if I could use a variable (rather than REPORT_LOCALE ,  it seems only work on reporting level) to say that the locale is different at each customer record.

Comment: This link is more about of i18n support of const values that comes not from datasource (DB)

Comment: The *REPORT_LOCALE* is a parameter for a whole report

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible using any of the standard resource references:

- `$R{resource.bundle.property}`
- `msg()` function
- `str()` function

For each record, supply the corresponding locale (or determine it based on other data, like the country and city -- chances are Quebec, Canada would be French [`fr_CA`] while Toronto, Canada would be English [`en_CA`]).

Once there's a map of locales to locations, use a [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString(java.lang.String)) (or [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#applyPattern(java.lang.String))?) to translate the key for a particular label.

Create a number of [resource bundle files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) with translations for the various labels. The file names must have a suffix that corresponds to the predetermined locale (e.g., `Bundle_fr_CA.properties`).

Change the label from static text to an expression. The expression instantiates a new resource bundle to look up the key (e.g., `"city.name"`) for its translated value, such as:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", new Locale("en", $F{country})).getString("city.name")
```

How the `"en"` is determined will be a bit of a chore, unless you can alter the database to get the user's language preferences. This means you'll also have to create a resource bundle for every language/country combination, which can be automated.