# Wicket - user data internationalization

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, internationalization, wicket

I'm writing an application using Wicket/Hibernate and I need to support many languages. How to make good internationalization of user data in a PostgreSQL database? Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: not sure i understand your needs. what kind of user data you like to i8n? Normally messages in different languages come from property files in wicket.

Comment: Hi bert. An example could be a type of a location. In English you may have the following data in a database: a type of a location whci can be a building, a swimming pool, a house, etc. And in Swedish: byggnad, pool, hus.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534646/how-to-design-a-database-schema-for-storing-text-in-multiple-languages

Comment: Hi donroby. It is not really the same question that I'm asking here. Since I would be using hibernate to get the data from database. I need something like django transmeta but for wicket/hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

There was an discussion way back on the ML. Key is using your own ResourceStreamLocator, see the discussion here:

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Datastore-localisation-Sanity-check-td1857084.html

Disclaimer, i have not used it, i just remembered the discussion.

hope it helped.