# support multiple languages on database side of an application

Tags: database, codeigniter, database-design, multilingual, multiple-languages

For the front end of our web app, we're using the Language class of Codeigniter to support multiple languages.

For the back end: Some values in the database also need to be in multiple languages as they will be displayed on the front end.

Here are two approaches I have read about:

- Using language-specific columns for each field: title_en, title_es, title_fr
- Using one separate table that contains all translations

Was wondering if there were any more (better) approaches we should be aware about?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database - quite a few suggestions are in there. I personally recommend the 3rd approach listed in the original question, since it allows easy fallback to the "primary" language using a outer join / NVL structure.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I usually do as well, but a table with all the columns:
element, en, fr, es
might be better, that way each row is referenced by the column *element* (or *id* or any other name) and adding or deleting languages will be really easy as all you have to do is add/delete a column