# How to store multilingual data?

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schema for a multilanguage database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database)

I am building  a very busy web application which has multilingual data. All this data is stored in a MySQL database. What is the best way to store this data? I have a few guesses though:

1. separate columns in the table for each language (like title_en, title_fr)
2. separate tables for each language (like pages_en, pages_fr)
3. cross table for translations (having an id in the pages table and having this linked id in a translation table where there are multiple columns like trans_en, trans_fr)
4. having non-multilingual data in one table for example pages and translations in one table per language (pages_en, pages_fr)
5. other?

Comment: Okay I see a problem with the second solution because if you add a new language and create a new table, all the non-multilingual columns must be copied to this new table. But it is probably faster than the first solution because the table is smaller in size.

Comment: Third solution makes primary tables very clean, but it is hard to do manual maintenance and the translation table will be killer big

Comment: Second solution is easy to expand to new languages (just adding columns) but can still get very big if the languages drastically expand)... A bit stuck here...

Comment: Thanks, checked this. But the solution is no good if you have multiple translation columns because joining will be really slow.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to make a site multilingual, then I would design the db as follows:

[image]

Every page in the application can have multiple languages. You only have to filter on the language id to get the desired language for the page.