# Want to change the Display language of text in MesageDialog in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a localized project where it is important for me to display text in local language eg: Hindi, tamil, etc.
I didn't had any problem in displaying the language in label, textfield, combo, etc using
this `comboDistrict.setFont(new Font("Kruti Dev 010", Font.BOLD, 17));`
i have text coming from database which i need to show in message dialog.
but i don't know how can i do the same in message dialog!

Please let me know the way to do this.
Thanx :)

Comment: If you use **eclipse** for developing, you can use default menu `Externalize Strings`. Or watch this [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)

Comment: ok. this is a good way, but i think this will not help me much, becuase the text i want to display is coming from the database.

Comment: You can try to localize values in your database. Maybe it can help you [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database)

Comment: To change the font, globally, you should take a look at the UIManager

Answer (score 0):

your answer **Internationalization and Localization**
[look here](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/i18n.html)

it may be use what you expecting.