# Run time Application Language Translation with database output

Tags: jsf, localization, internationalization, multilingual

I have one application having property file for both languages and my JSF UI is now got translated to desired language.

My problem is with the database inputs. I want a common database which will support both languages eg. French and English. But when application language changes it should change the output and input.

That means if I type some word in french by selecting French as my application language at run time it should translate it to English and save it to database and vice versa for the query output.

My project uses maven java and PrimeFaces

Thanks in advance. Waiting for solution

Comment: "*if I type some word in french by selecting French as my application language at run time it **should translate** it to English and save it to database and vice versa.*" Translate? Localization does not imply dynamic translation from one language to another at all. You need to have a localized multilingual database to store data separately in both the languages French and English (and others, if any). See some views [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316780/1391249).

Comment: Thanks Tiny, But can I use some third party application for translation?
Will my Database suffer from data integrity issue??
Because I want the application switching swift and there should not be any change in database query output after switching language