# Android data inserting in sqlite in different language

Tags: android, database, sqlite, multilingual

When the user changes the language of their mobile, the data I used to insert in sqlite of my application changing to the respective lanuage.

How to prevent language change in my appliction?

Comment: You can have a look a this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824537/the-way-to-change-database-helper-to-support-multiple-languages)

Comment: How can I prevent inserting in other language, My problem is inserting some data in sqlite. When inserting the data are updating in db with different language which user changed in android settings.

Comment: If you don't want user to update record then you must first check your system language and if it is your preferred language then and then only allow user to update record otherwise you can show popup or toast to user.

Comment: thanks for your help