# Implementing a fallback in fetching multilingual data

Tags: mysql, database-design, localization, multilingual

I'm in the process of translating an existing MySQL table according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323365/1329111) answer. In this case I'm dealing with menu_items, and my table structure now looks as follows:

- menu_items

  - id
  - sort_position
- menu_item_translations

  - menu_item_id
  - language ENUM('nl', 'en')
  - label
  - tooltip

I'm now looking for a way to JOIN these tables in such a way, that I can use one language as a fallback while searching for records of another.

The standard query would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    menu_items mi
INNER JOIN menu_item_translations mit
    ON mit.menu_item_id = mi.id
WHERE
    mit.language = 'en';
```

But I would like 'nl' to be the fallback in case an English menu item has not been found. I'm not too keen on stored procedures, but I can use them if I have to.

Is there any way to implement a fallback in this query, without too much performance loss or ugliness?

Answer (score 0):

Realised right after posting this question that the answer is fairly simple;

```
SELECT 
    mi.*,
    COALESCE(mit.label, mit_fb.label) AS label
FROM
    menu_items mi
LEFT JOIN menu_item_translations mit
    ON mit.menu_item_id = mi.id
    AND mit.language = 'en'
LEFT JOIN menu_item_translations mit_fb
    ON mit_fb.menu_item_id = mi.id
    AND mit_fb.language = 'nl';
```

This does exactly what I want.