# SQL columns for each language?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, localization

For a case where a software will only target a specific country, that has 4 in-use languages, out of which only 2 are mainly important, how would you design DB tables that need Descriptions for its items in those 2 languages? Is it a good idea to have 2 columns: DescriptionLang1, DescriptionLang2?

Comment: "Localization" is the term describing what you are trying to do. Lots of resources online about how you might attempt to implement localization, including similar questions here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316780/schema-for-a-multilanguage-database

Comment: That may work but if you then add more languages you have to edit your entire DB structure.  If you are not doing this with every column you could have a lookup table for that column a 1 to many relationship and the values are stored in the second table with a language ID and matching value for the main table and join/pull from there